# Как отловить нажатие checkbox bootstrap

Tags: html, jquery, jsp

Всем доброго времени суток, помогите разобраться, есть html форма с подключенным фреймворком bootstrap которая отображает данные из БД, мне нужно разместить checkbox и если он нажат выполнять другой запрос к БД, сервер Tomcat, собственно среда разработки java. Сам checkbox я разместил:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" value="" name ="checkb">Test</label>
```

а как теперь отловить его нажатие сервлетом не понимаю, обьясните пожалуйста. Спасибо

Comment: Посмотрите пример http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_checked если чекбокс выбран, то он передается в параметрах формы.

Comment: @SergeyMitrofanov Вот теперь понял в servlet мы отлавливает наше значение в value, если name нам вернуло value значит checkbox нажат. Спасибо за подсказку

Comment: @SergeyMitrofanov А можно еще и заголовки таблиц менять ? или так просто уже не получиться ??

Comment: Можно. Но это уже двумя словами не объяснить. Попробуйте начать изучение с этой темы http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243554/if-checkbox-is-checked-do-this